How to force clang assembler to emit the `rex.W` prefix?
When writing inline assembly, is there a way to force the use of the rex.W prefix?
So instead of
"psllq $12, %%xmm1\n"

generating 66 0f 73 f1 0c, I want 66 48 0f 73 f1 0c, with the extra 0x48 rex.W prefix.
EDIT:
I made a mistake with the initial title, the problem is with clang not GCC.
insn_sse2.c:11794:11: error: unexpected token in argument list
         "rex.W psllq $12, %%xmm1\n"
          ^
<inline asm>:7:13: note: instantiated into assembly here
rex.W psllq $12, %xmm1



Funnily enough you just add the rex.W prefix :)  rex.W psllq $12, %%xmm1

Why do you need it?

Clang accepts rex64 psllq $12, %xmm1, but unfortunately misassembles it.

You can just add the rex.W prefix:
rex.W psllq $12, %xmm1

This is exactly how GNU binutils will disassemble the opcode bytes you have given.  From a file psllq.s with the contents
.byte 0x66, 0x48, 0x0f, 0x73, 0xf1, 0x0c

we can run as psllq.s -o psllq.o && objdump -d psllq.o to obtain:

psllq.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   66 48 0f 73 f1 0c       rex.W psllq $0xc,%xmm1


That doesn't seem to work with clang (and this needs to work with both GCC and clang).

@PaulFloyd Is there any particular reason why you need a rex.W prefix specifically?

You can always write out the .byte pseudo-op manually…

That's probably what I'll do.

@fuz not surprisingly this is for a Valgrind testcase. At the moment psllq is handled without rex.W but not with rex.W. I need a testcase with rex.W (and probably also for a few other similar opcodes).

See https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=487439

@PaulFloyd Makes sense.  In this case I recommend pinning the registers used using register asm (...) variables and then manually emitting the exact instruction bytes you need using .byte.

@user3840170, you can't just use .byte for the REX prefix, because the REX prefix has to come after the 66 prefix that is part of the PSLLQ instruction. So you would have to use .byte for the full instruction.
